# Finding the subspace generated by set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V = $\Bbb{R}^3$. Find the subspace generated by set $A=\{v_1, v_2\}$, where $v_1=(1, -2, -1)$ and $v_2=(2, 1, 1)$.

My attempt:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
k_1 + 2k_2=x \\ 
-2k_1 + k_2=y \\ 
-k_1+k_2=z
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

It follows then that $k_1=x-2k_2$ and $k_1=\frac{y+k_2}{2}$. So, $k_2=\frac{2x+y}{5}$. Substituting the previous results in the third equation, we have $6x+3y-5z=0$ which according to the answer key should actually be $x+3y-5z=0$.

What am I missing?

Comment: It’s always a good idea to check your own work. For this problem, you could check your solution against $v_1$ and $v_2$ by plugging them into the equation that you derived. Neither one satisfies this equation, so you know that your solution is incorrect even without checking the answer key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subspace is a plane $ax+by+cz=0$ therefore

- $a-2b-c=0$
- $2a+b+c=0$

and adding up

- $3a=b$
- $a=-\frac15 c$

therefore

$$x+3y-5z=0$$

As an alternative by cross product

$$\vec n=\begin{vmatrix}\vec i&\vec j&\vec k\\1&-2&-1\\2&1&1\end{vmatrix}=(-1,-3,5)$$

Comment: @mfl Thanks I update!

Comment: I was not aware of that approach unit now, so here are some questions. How did you conclude that the subspace is a plane that crosses the origin? Why did you change the sign of the vector when writing the constraint?

Comment: @MauricioMendes By the definition given for the subspace as a span of 2 linearly independent vectors we can directly conclude that it is a plane through the origin (indeed the origin is reached by $0v_1+0v_2$).

Comment: @MauricioMendes Which change of sign are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to your alternative solution.

Comment: @MauricioMendes The sign doesn't matter indeed a plane has infinite normal vectors and if $n$ is a normal also $-n$ is  anormal. Indeed flipping the vectors we obtain $$\vec n=\begin{vmatrix}\vec i&\vec j&\vec k\\2&1&1\\1&-2&-1\end{vmatrix}=(1,3,-5)$$. Also note that the plane $x+3y-5z=0$ is the same plane with equation $-x-3y+5z=0$.

Comment: I got it now. What if it were polynomials or matrices instead of vectors?

Comment: @MauricioMendes The concept and methods are exactly the same!

Comment: I though so, but my professor argues that polymials, matrices and vectors are different objects. For instance, the polynomial $p=3x^2+2x+1$ cannot be written as $p=(3, 2, 1)$. Thus the methods you presented could not be used on exams. Is her reasoning right?

Comment: @MauricioMendes Of course they are completely different objects but from the linear algebra point of view they can be treated as vector spaces in the same way. Maybe your professor was referring to something different.

Comment: She was not, that's why I asked you. Where can I find out more about the method you used? I am using "Elementary Linear Algebra" by Anton and Rorres.

Comment: Here on MSE you can find a lot of material on solved problems also for vector spaces involving mstrices and polynomials. Moreover there are also specific OP with many suggested readings and book. Take look here and search for that material.

Answer (score 0):

You lost a minus sign:   should be $k_1=\frac{-y+k_2}2$.  Then $x-2k_2=\frac{-y+k_2}2\implies k_2=\frac{2x+y}5\implies k_1=\frac{-2y+x}5\implies 3y+x=5z\implies x+3y-5z=0$...